# How to sort a mock object in python?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I am mocking the `path` attribute of an object that is used for sorting. However, trying to sort objects fails:

```py
    def __lt__(self, other: RealObject) -> bool:
        """Sort based on path."""
>       return self.path < other.path
E       TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'MagicMock'
```

So I tried extending MagicMock, but it still fails:

```py
class MockPath(MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, name: Optional[str] = None, *args, **kw) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.name = name or str(random.randint(1, 10000))

    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.name < other.name
```

```py
    def __lt__(self, other: RealObject) -> bool:
        """Sort based on path."""
>       return self.path < other.path
E       TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MockPath' and 'MockPath'
```

How can I allow the mocked objects to sort? It's not important what they sort to, I just don't want it to fail.

Comment: How exactly are you performing the patching? Typically, you don't need to patch a simple attribute; you just create objects with the appropriate value. Patching is more suited to replacing an expensive function with something faster and limited to what is needed for the test.

Comment: @chepner I was just setting `my_object.path = MagicMock()`. `my_object.path` is a `pathlib.Path` object and I didn't want to create a real Path for certain tests.

Comment: You may be able to use a `pathlib.PurePath` instead.

Comment: @chepner unfortunately purepaths don't support all the same methods. For instance, when adding objects to a database, I use `path.resolve()` to normalize the paths, which magicmock happily took, but purepath will not.

Comment: OK, back to the original question: what is your code that actually tries to patch some object with your mock? It's not clear that you need a mock at all, rather than an plain, ordinary object that has a `name` attribute.

Comment: @chepner in my test:

`my_obj = my_object(title="my_obj", path=MagicMock())`